# Error in opening a new window using window.open

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am using the following two functions in JavaScript to open two different windows:

```
function A(int a) {
    var url = "/someAction.do?operation=getDetailsA&id="+a;
    window.open(url,
        'FormA',
        'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=800,height=700,left=0,top=0,fullscreen=0');
}

function B(int a) {
    var url = "/someAction.do?operation=updateDetailsA&id="+a;
    window.open(url,
        'FormB',
        'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=800,height=700,left=0,top=0,fullscreen=0');
}
```

The function A displays the results in a new window and the function B enables to update the values in a new window. When i first click on the link to update, it works fine. When I click on the link to display the details, it works fine as well.
But the problem is after clicking on the display link, if I click to update, only a blank screen showed up. If I first click the update, it works fine, but after clicking the function A (get details), function B (update details) does not work.

Hopefully I am able to describe my problem, I tried using `window.location.href`, but not helpful, any suggestions, would really appreciate?

Answer (score 0):

You are having different names for the windows `formA` and `formB` may be that is causing the blank screen. Have a same window name and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks DDK, I also tried using the same window names for formA and formB, but didnot work for me.